# This function creates and returns a list of all countries whose nth letter matches the letter in the parameter in Python

Tags: python, json, python-3.x, list, for-loop

`get_list_of_countries_whose_nth_letter_is(3, “m”)` would return a list of every country whose THIRD letter (i.e. index 2) is the letter m:

```py
['Armenia', 'Cambodia', 'Cameroon', 'Comoros', 'Dominica', 'Dominican Republic', 'Gambia', 'Jamaica', 'Namibia', 'Romania', 'Samoa', 'Somalia', 'Yemen', 'Zambia', 'Zimbabwe']
```

Note: you MUST use a for loop.

This is what I have I know it is just printing letters with "M" but If I could get some input into printing out country whose THIRD letter (i.e. index 2) is the letter m.

```py
def get_list_of_countries_whose_nth_letter_is(n_letter):
    countrie = []
    for countries1 in countries:
        if "M" in countries1.upper():
            countrie.append(countries1)
    print(countrie)

['Armenia', 'Bahamas', 'Belgium', 'Cambodia', 'Cameroon', 'Colombia', 'Comoros', 'Congo, Democratic Republic of the', 'Denmark', 'Dominica', 'Dominican Republic', 'East Timor', 'Federated States of Micronesia', 'Gambia', 'Germany', 'Guatemala', 'Jamaica', 'Luxembourg', 'Madagascar', 'Malawi', 'Malaysia', 'Maldives', 'Mali', 'Malta', 'Marshall Islands', 'Mauritania', 'Mauritius', 'Mexico', 'Moldova', 'Monaco', 'Mongolia', 'Montenegro', 'Morocco', 'Mozambique', 'Myanmar (Burma)', 'Namibia', 'North Macedonia (Macedonia)', 'Oman', 'Panama', 'Romania', 'Samoa', 'San Marino', 'Sao Tome and Principe', 'Solomon Islands', 'Somalia', 'Suriname', 'Turkmenistan', 'United Arab Emirates', 'United Kingdom', 'Vietnam', 'Yemen', 'Zambia', 'Zimbabwe']
```

Comment: Do you know how to access the 3rd character of a string... if we simplify it for a moment... if you had just `country = 'something'` - how would you access the 3rd character of `country` ?

Comment: Also - it looks like your function is expected to take two arguments... you're only accepting one and your "m" is hard-coded inside your function - I doubt that's what's expected

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Riel,  you code has issue on finding the 3rd letter of `M`.  Try this and see if it can help you understand the problem:

[Updates] - if your function will require two parameters: a letter, and an index - then you can change it:

```
def countries_nth_letter_is(letter, index): 
    for country in countries:

    if country[index].upper() == letter:
        .....
```

def countries_nth_letter_is(letter):

```
ans = []

for country in countries:
    
    if country[2].upper() == letter:
        ans.append(country)

return ans
```

if **name** == '**main**':
countries = ['Armenia', 'Bahamas', 'Belgium', 'Cambodia', 'Cameroon', 'Colombia', 'Comoros', 'Congo, Democratic Republic of the',
'Denmark', 'Dominica', 'Dominican Republic', 'East Timor', 'Federated States of Micronesia', 'Gambia', 'Germany',
'Guatemala', 'Jamaica', 'Luxembourg', 'Madagascar', 'Malawi', 'Malaysia', 'Maldives', 'Mali', 'Malta', 'Marshall Islands',
'Mauritania', 'Mauritius', 'Mexico', 'Moldova', 'Monaco', 'Mongolia', 'Montenegro', 'Morocco', 'Mozambique', 'Myanmar (Burma)',
'Namibia', 'North Macedonia (Macedonia)', 'Oman', 'Panama', 'Romania', 'Samoa', 'San Marino', 'Sao Tome']

```
print(countries_nth_letter_is('M'))
```

```
Output:   [cut off some from original list... ]
```

['Armenia', 'Cambodia', 'Cameroon', 'Comoros', 'Dominica', 'Dominican Republic', 'Gambia', 'Jamaica', 'Namibia', 'Romania', 'Samoa']

Comment: In the strange scenario of a country (there's not any that exist as far as I'm aware - but there's always the point of not trusting your inputs) - it might be nice if you show how to either handle an `IndexError`, eg: `'xy'[2]` or maybe cheat slightly and do a slice rather than direct indexing, eg: `if country[2:3].upper() == letter`...

Comment: Good Point. I will trust the author has to learn how to handle those `edge cases` himself.  Here just try to offer some min. guidance and tips (based on the PO.)

Answer (score 0):

there's a couple of ways:
Using a [list comprehension](https://www.w3schools.com/python/python_lists_comprehension.asp)

```py
def matches(countries, letter, n):
    return [country for country in countries if country[n]==letter]
```

which expands to

```py
def matches(countries, letter, n):
    results = []
    for country in countries:
        if country[n] == letter:
            results.append(country)
    return results
```

If you can use generators:

```py
def matches(countries, letter, n):
    for country in countries:
        if country[n] == letter:
            yield country

def matches(countries, letter, n):
    # return (country for country in countries if country[n]==letter)
    yield from (country for country in countries if country[n]==letter)
```